# Golang enclosure rule for csv parsing

Tags: csv, go

I have the following problem. I have to read csv files that are delimited by '|', and some fields have large json strings in which some contain '|'.
The fields are enclosed in single-quotes.
How can I specify in GOLANG that the fields are enclosed in single quotes.

This is how it is setup right now:

```
fx := csv.NewReader(fz)

fx.Comma = '|'
fx.LazyQuotes = true
fx.FieldsPerRecord = 16
```

I don't see anything in GODOCS options for enclosure rules.
Does anyone have a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, however, luckily Go is written in, well, Go.

You could copy `$GOROOT/src/pkg/encoding/csv/reader.go`, then modify [line 274](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/csv/reader.go?#L274), 289, 297 and 303 to use `'\''` instead of `'"'` and you're good to go.

Comment: Good to know! But I can't do this in production :D

Comment: Why not? you can copy it to your own package and use it just fine. instead of `import "encoding/csv"` use `import "your-project-path/csv"`.

Comment: Yes, it works! But I feel kind of awkward doing this :))

Comment: I think I'm going to make a feature request about this.

Comment: Here it is: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8458&thanks=8458&ts=1406822277

Comment: I might make a CL for it later.